# zookeeper server cannot be started with member server ip as ipv6

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ipv6

I have two members that I want to form the cluster with the following configuration in zookeeper.properties:

```
host1:
server.0=localhost:2888:3888
server.1=[64:aaaa:bbbb:1000::8]:2888:3888

host2:
server.0=[64:aaaa:bbbb:1000::1]:2888:3888
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
```

zookeeper server cannot be started with this console output:

```
sh-5.0$ echo $ZOO_LOG4J_PROP
DEBUG,ROLLINGFILE
sh-5.0$  ./zkServer.sh start
/usr/bin/java
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /var/lib/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... FAILED TO START
```

But I did not get any DEBUG log from zookeeper.log.

Due to this issue, both hosts cannot join the quorum due to the Exception below:

```
2023-01-09 02:13:27,061 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Close of session 0x0
java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.readLength(NIOServerCnxn.java:544)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:332)
```

The zookeeper version is 3.7.1.

How to troubleshoot this further now?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the `64:aaaa:bbbb:1000:::` addresses? Those are reserved. You should either use assigned Global addresses (in the `2000::/3` range) or proper ULA (in the `fd00::/8` range using a random Global ID - the 40 bits following the `fd`). You cannot just make up addresses.

Comment: The root cause of this issue is found. This is due to missing ip6table DNAT rules that might be established in the late version of docker engine (20.10 and up). In ipv4, there would be rules like the following:

-A POSTROUTING -s 169.254.8.2/32 -d 169.254.8.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3888 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i cbr-net -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3888 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.254.8.2:3888
-A DOCKER -d 169.254.8.2/32 ! -i cbr-net -o cbr-net -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3888 -j ACCEPT

BTW, these ipv6 addresses were just made up by myself for internal testing.

Comment: IPv6 should not use NAT. If you are using NAT, then you are trying to apply IPv4-thinking to IPv6, but that is not the way to do it. NAT is a kludge to extend the life of IPv4 until IPv6 is ubiquitous. IPv6, unlike IPv4, has enough addresses to restore the IP end-to-end paradigm where every host can have a unique Global IP address, and NAT breaks that. There is no NAT standard for IPv6 the way there is for IPv4.

Comment: These 3 rules for ipv6 are created by docker engine for each container that needs to do port mapping between the container and host. I will see if similar DOCKER rules will be there when ipv6 is enabled with docker 20.10. The docker version of my system is 19.03.8.

Comment: sorry for the typo. I meant the above 3 ipv4 rules...